# Cocoa global hotkey consume key event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyevent, macos-carbon

I've been trying for hours to use global hotkeys and "consume" the key event so it is not forwarded any more to the application where the key event is originally coming from.

So what I want to do is:
- a user presses a shortcut with application A in front, e.g. Cmd+F3
- my application (application B) receives this shortcut through the global event handler and sends mouse and keyboard events to application A

It's probably easiest to think of it as a macro.

I'm using DDHotkey and it works quite fine. The problem I have is that DDHotkey doesn't "consume" the key events and modifiers. That means that when my application starts sending mouse and keyboard events, the Cmd key from the actual global shortcut is still pressed.

This leads to erroneous behavior in my case (I'm double-clicking a textfield programmatically and that doesn't open when Cmd is pressed for example).

So what I'd like to do is really consume the key event and the modifier keys so that they are not forwarded to application A. Alternatively, I would "flush" the event queue before sending the key events to application A.

Is there any way to achieve this easily?

Comment: Search SO for "event tap".

Comment: I did and I have working code using CGEventTap. The problem remains. Can't "kill" the modifier key. The only workaround I could find was to get application A to the front and send a key up event for Cmd. It doesn't work when sending the event from application B using CGEventPostToPSN(), only when application A is active and CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent) is used.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending events without modifier flags? How do you know which modifier keys to consume? You don't know if your hotkey is going to be pressed.

Answer (score 0):

An even more reliable approach if it works for your use case would likely be to *not* script the UI by triggering mouse events and key presses, and instead use the *Accessibility API* to trigger the more high-level actions (like using Accessibility to tell a button it has been pressed). Unless the app contains some unfortunate code, that should not look at the modifier keys.

Telling the OS from an event monitor to remove key states would probably cause lots of issues: It would be confusing if the user then actually released the physical keys and a second keyUp came in. Even if the OS tries to avoid that, it is just asking for other edge case bugs - what if the user pressed a modifier key while your code is scripting the UI?

But if the applications you are scripting do not support Accessibility, nor AppleScript, nor any other more high level approach to automation, what you could do is wait for the user to release your hotkey (i.e. wait for keyUp events) and only then trigger your scripted actions. Might be necessary to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:0.0 to get out of the keyUp handler before you do that.